# Django query engine - Migrating from 1.11 to 2.0

Tags: python, django, database

I'm trying to migrate from Django 1.11 to 2.0. After running my test suite, I'm getting in many db transactions the error:

`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: subquery has too many columns`

, which didn't happen while running the test suite with 1.11.

The database I'm using is postgres (with psycopg2-binary v2.7.4 module).

Did anything change in the query engine between Django 1.11 to 2.0? I can't see anything like that in the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/), nor anywhere else.

Comment: You could try running git bisect to find the change that causes your test suite to fail.

Comment: @Alasdair the only thing i changed was the Django version. 
Before the dependency update, the test suite ran correctly, after the update it doesn't. And this is due to the db error aforementioned.
Running git bisect on my project won't help in this scenario, imo.

Comment: I mean run git bisect on Django to find the change in Django that causes your test to fail.

Answer (score 0):

This is the section you're looking for: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#database-backend-api

You'll also want to change the engine name to `django.db.backends.postgresql`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#id1

Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, I mis-read the question. It's too early here on the east coast, but I'll leave the answer in case it it useful.